# Appfabric Caching: Configuration Provider as single point of failure

Tags: caching, distributed, appfabric

After doing some initial research into using Appfabric for caching, my understanding is that the configuration provider for the cluster is a single point of failure as mentioned here:

[MSDN](http://64.4.11.251/en-us/library/ee790934.aspx)

I want to use appfabric just for distributed caching, particularly for the tagging features. What are the options to avoid having the configuration provider as this failure point? I thought of two but not sure if one is better or if there are any other options.

(1) Create my own caching service configuration provider. I'm guessing this is possible (?) but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'd probably make a provider that fetched the xml file from S3 since I'm already using AWS.

(2) Configure each cache as a single node cluster and then create a proxy client that uses the individual nodes as a distributed cache, a la a memcached type client.

Thoughts or recommendations, or anything else I should consider in making this decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it *is* a single point of failure.

Microsoft's recomended solutions seem to be:

- (SQL Server provider) Use SQL Server
  clustering. In my *limited*
  experience of it, using SQL Server
  clustering for this is probably a
  case of 'the cure is worse than the
  disease' i.e. it brings a lot of
  pain. Unless you've already got a SQL
  Server cluster available, avoid!
- (XML
  provider) Use Windows Server
  clustering. I have even less
  knowledge of this than SQL
  clustering, so I can't say how well (or otherwise)
  this might work. It doesn't strike me as a trivial thing to do, though.

You can create your own configuration provider by implementing the [ICustomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.icustomprovider.aspx) interface and making [some registry entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383419.aspx). Using AWS seems like a really good idea to make the config provider resilient, I'd be interested to see how you got on with this.

Creating a proxy client seems to me like you'd be making a lot of work for yourself, at that point it feels like you'd be more fighting against AppFabric rather than working with it.

Comment: I agree about the proxy client. It would be an ugly solution.

I am thinking that implementing ICustomProvider would be the way to go, but I can't find a solid enough example to run with it. Generally I think I might be able to hack it out but some methods take object types, are vague in their description, etc. so it would be really tough. I think I'll keep hacking away at this because I think it would be a good solution.

Comment: @Luke I just did a really quick Google for `ICustomProvider` and didn't find any examples. I suspect the way to go with it is to have a look at the published code for the SQL Server/XML providers in Reflector combined with examining the SQL Server/XML schemas.

Comment: Man somehow reflector didnt even cross my mind. Worked on it today for a while. I'll post my results when im done. Thanks!

Comment: Got something working. Here's what I did. Hopefully its helpful to someone! http://bit.ly/gmfZ67

Comment: XML on a SAN share is generally a lot easier/more cost effective than bulky, unnecessary Windows clustering ...

Answer (score 1):

We have also tried  [AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/)  but it gave us fair few headaches like for one there's no API access which is making it very difficult to use our current unit testing strategy. We have now moved to  [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html)  that is better option than AppFabric. NCache provides tagging feature and it is not a single point of failure.